# Flutter unable to build app for android 12

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, android-manifest

I am trying to build my Flutter App to support Android 12. It works fine up to Android 11, but is not supporting Android 12. I trying to add android:exported="true" or "false" but not working. If someone know please help

Error logs

Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

> adb: failed to install
> /Users/shrikrishna/Manoj/Projects/Flutter/Myapp/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
> installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl158598875.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
> file line #1230):
> com.dooboolab.TauEngine.FlautoBackgroundAudioService: Targeting S+
> (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for
> android:exported be defined when intent filters are present] Error
> launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.

Comment: what about your sdk version?

Comment: my sdk version is 31.

Comment: Specifically, this service `FlautoBackgroundAudioService` requires the `exported` flag. you can manually add it if this is coming from a library.

Comment: I not used FlautoBackgroundAudioService

Comment: @user14805610 , are you using some audio library in flutter? Maybe that library uses this class

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `android:exported="true"` or `"false"` on every activity, services, or broadcast receiver that using any `intent-filter`. Please note, if you have multiple dependencies, and in these dependencies if they have their own activity, services, or broadcast receiver, we also need to add these `android:exported` also on each of it.

But obviously, some dependencies may be not yet updated to comply with this one. so for now we can solve it by adding it in our own app Manifest.

to do this:

### 1. Check for merged manifest

First build the app, and then check for the merged manifest on the build folder. This usually on directory `./build/app/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/out/AndroidManifest.xml`
Open it, and find any tag `<intent-filter>` on this file. and note the activity, service or broadcast class name. foe example:

```
        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                ....
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

### 2. Modify our app Manifest.

Open your project app manifest, and add tools namespace on the manifest tag. `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Then add these class on the manifest with the additional attribute `android:exported="false"` and make sure to add `tools:node="merge"` on it also. For example:

```
        <receiver
           android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" 
           android:exported="false"
           tools:node="merge" />
```

you dont need to add the other attribute or intent filter on your Project Manifest, since its already added on the plugins Manifest file. you only need to add these exported and tools:node="merge" to make the manifest attributes and value to be merged.

Then Lastly, run it locally first and make sure all of the Activity/services/broadcast receiver with intent-filter is having these attributes (NOTE: `tools:node` attribute will be not present on the merged Manifest.).

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your project to the most recent flutter version.
Upgrade your dependancies, seach tags  in all AndroidManifest.xml files, also in your manifest dependancies files. and change
`service ....></service>`
or
`<service .... android:exported="false"></service>`

to
`<service .... android:exported="true"></service>`

Answer (score 0):

just follow steps :

1 set targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion 32

2 open AndroidManifest.xml , in application tag add this -

usesCleartextTraffic="true"

androidSupportRtl="true"

3 set android:exported="true" in activity

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach to cope with this error. In my case I have the receiver core component called `com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver` without the property exported. Where? I didn't know.

So I found inside my plugin folder which it exists after running flutter pub get. After searching I read the manifest of **flutter_local_notifications** version "4.0.1+2" and see the error.
Therefore, I added android:exported="true" on it and retry the flutter run on my emulator.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is not a solution because I have to rewrite this manifest after cleaning the project.